# C function call from dispatch_async global crashes but works on main queue

Tags: objective-c, macos, garbage-collection, grand-central-dispatch

[image]Im facing a strange issue in which if i invoke a c static library function from dispatch global queue the code crashes in the C library. But if i call the same code from main thread it runs successfully.Below is summary of code snippet:-

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
// Below is the C code
int returnCode = calculate_feature_vector([dest_folder UTF8String],[dest_path 
UTF8String],feature_vector);
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    completion(distanceMap);
});
```

Im not sure why its crashing, Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you executing the function concurrently?

Comment: I call the c function many times in a for loop but the crash comes at first iteration of the for loop only.

Comment: Unmitigated concurrence never ends well, but that is secondary to the primary problem.   Sounds like there is something in `calculate_feature_vector` that has a dependency on the main thread.   Where did that function come from?  Show the crash backtrace, too.

Comment: The function is exposed from a static c library. Attached is the backtrace.iTypeTXT is another C function inside the librarywhich generates some images where it crashes.

Comment: @bbum Can we call the c library function in another process using NSTask?

Comment: Ok-- sounds like the static library has a hard dependency on the main thread.  Got source?  Because that should be fixed!   Yes, you could use NSTask, but you're quickly going to run into sandboxing issues.

Comment: The c source code is running on single thread, any idea how can that hard dependency be removed?

Answer (score 0):

Any calls that involve the macOS GUI or that handle text, including key translators, text input sources and any calls to the text service manager should be done on the main thread or you may crash. I don’t know the dependencies of that library but you should look for any that I mention here. If you have them then you should build an XPC service to handle this on the main thread and not block your UI.

Answer (score 0):

Im able to solve the issue now. The solution was to wrap the c code in objective c class and then call the objective c code from dispatch queue. Previously I was calling the c code directly from the dispatch queue.

Comment: Your solution sounds like it fixed a symptom, but not the problem.  That may be good enough, though. :).  Sounds like a potential memory management error that is now hidden by the class (and might actually be a correct solution).

Comment: Yes, you are right the crash is on generating some images in the c code.Is it that all the image processing is done on main thread?

Comment: Depends on how they generate the images.  If they are using UIImage, then the threading requirements are quite specific.

Comment: Any idea how can I create the png images on background thread?

Comment: Not without seeing the image creation code.   Probably want to ask a new question about that.